# WP как вывести все метки кастомной категории?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть вот такая кастомная категория (таксономия) `vendors` Заполненная метками

```
/*
 *  Регистрация таксономии производителей
 */

add_action( 'init', 'create_vendor_taxonomies' );

// функция, создающая таксономии "vendors" для постов типа "vendor"
function create_vendor_taxonomies(){

    // Добавляем недревовидную таксономию 'vendors' (как метки)
    register_taxonomy('vendors', array('vendor', 'post'), array(
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'labels'        => array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Производители', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Vendor', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Поиск производителей' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'Все производители' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Vendor' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Vendor:' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Править производителя' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Обновить производителя' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Добавить нового производителя' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'Имя нового производителя' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Vendors' ),
        ),
        'show_ui'       => true,
        'show_in_rest'  => true,
        'query_var'     => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
    ));
}
```

[image: vendors]
создал под нее страницу `page-vendors.php`
Вопрос как в ней вывести списком все метки которые к ней относятся (с пагинацией) Пишу вот так:

```
<ul class="vendors">

                    <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'vendors',
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                        'paged' => get_query_var("paged") ?: 1,
                    );

                    $query = new WP_Query($args);

                    if ($query->have_posts()) {

                        $term = get_queried_object();
                        $termID = $term->term_id;

                        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                        
                            <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></li>
                        
                        <?php endwhile;
                    } ?>
                    <?php get_template_part("components/pagination");
                    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                </ul>
```

но оно работает не верно... я пробовал итерировать по `while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_tag();` но тогда вообще ломается(

Comment: Уточните, Вам нужно вывести все метки из таксономии vendors? Или все записи которые относятся к таксономии vendors? Потому что WP_Query выводит пост тайпы, для вывода таксономий используется другая ф-ция.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вам нужно вывести список таксономий, а не пост тайпов, то имейте ввиду что WP_Query выводит как раз таки пост тайпы, а не таксономии. Для вывода таксономий можно использовать [get_terms()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_terms). В WordPress пагинация предусмотрена только для пост тайпов, потому пагинацию придется писать самостоятельно. Например можно добавить GET параметры в URL с номером страницы.

```
<?php
$paged = isset( $_GET['term_page'] ) ? intval( $_GET['term_page'] ) : 1;
if( $paged < 1 ) $paged = 1;

$args = [
    'taxonomy' => 'vendors',
    'number'   => 10,
    'offset'   => ($paged - 1) * 10
    'orderby'  => 'date',
    'order'    => 'ASC',
];

$terms = get_terms( $args );

if( !empty( $terms ) ) : ?>
    <ul class="vendors">
        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) : ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'term_page', $paged-- ) ); ?>">Предыдущая</a> | <a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg('term_page', $paged++) ); ?>">Следующая</a>
```